# Current receipt invalid or mismatched ds person id + Included images

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm setting up In-App purchasing for my Mac App. I currently am able to get the product from iTunes Connect, and even request a purchase. I'm pretty stumped with this error message, and am really hoping someone has been here before and can offer some assistance.

I am getting the (very helpful) localized error: Transaction error: Unknown Error.

I've included the two images of successful Mac App Store authentication, and error message. All I'm able to figure out is that the failedTransaction is being called from the SKPaymentTransaction.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did. Archive in Xcode. Then distribute -> mac installer -> double-click .pkg file & install.

That seems to download the _MASReceipt and all is well when including

```
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL] path]]) {
        NSLog(@"to get sandbox receipt, the app must be launched from outside xcode");
        exit(173);
    }
```

Comment: And, had to include if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL] path]]) {
        NSLog(@"to get sandbox receipt, the app must be launched from outside xcode");
        exit(173);
    }

Comment: Where does the check need to be included in the app?